# User cannot create new tag

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am building a BlogApp and I am trying to implement a feature so user `cannot create new tags And can only use existing tags`, So I am checking the form at the time of submit
But When i save the form with existing tags than it is `showing error every time`.

models.py

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

views.py

```
from taggit.models import Tag

def new_blog_post(request):
    existingTags = Tag.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BlogPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.user= request.user
            return redirect('qa:questions')

    else:
        form = BlogPostForm()
```

I have also tried by looping the `tags query` like :-

> Tag object is not iterable

**Note :** I am using [Django-Taggit](https://pypi.org/project/django-taggit/) package for `Tagging Functionality`

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is just how to handle the tags queryset :

```
Tag.objects.all()
```

This instruction return something like this :

```
<QuerySet [<Tag: music>, <Tag: science>]>
```

And from my little experience, it sometime hard to play with this kind of structure.

Try then `existingTags = list(Tag.objects.names())` to have a result like this : `['music', 'science']` (I used **names** attribute of the Tag object, the **slug** attribute exist too for conveniences).

And after you can check `if blog_tags in existingTags:`

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion . But It didn't work

Comment: Try then to print `blog_tags = form.cleaned_data['tags']` and `list(Tag.objects.names())` in the console. Past the result here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the `blog_tags` will be a list or a string element.

You're trying to compare it with a resultset.

Try converting the resultset to a list using `.values_list('name', flat=True)` and check for existence in it.

You'll get good idea if you print the existingTags and blog_tags.

Comment: When i try `.values_list('name', flat=True)` then it is successfully creating `string in list` but it is still showing the same result

Comment: Did you try printing the values?

Comment: Yes it shows :- **Blog Post's tags are** `<QuerySet ['Bike']>` AND  **Existing tags are** 
`<QuerySet ['Health', 'Bike']>`, But It is still not saving the `Blog Post`.

Comment: Is it going inside the if block?

Comment: Yes , I am checking `if new tags are in existingTags. If True then save post if Not then show custom error`

Comment: you're saying the control is going inside `if blog_tags in existingTags:` but still printing `You cannot create a New Tags` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236593/discussion-between-underoos-and-lars).

Comment: As far as I know, the control shouldn't go inside the if block as you're checking for queryset inside queryset.
check for 'bike' in ['health', 'bike'] instead of <QuerySet['bike']> in <QuerySet['health', 'bike']>